# private static throughout code

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am on a new project, and the legacy java code is filled with classes that are using a mix of private static methods, and public static methods.

It's very hard to follow.

For example:

```
public Car {
    private static checkGas(){ 
       ..
    }

    public static startCar(){
        checkGas();
    }
}
```

Is there some design pattern I never heard of that would make this applicable?

I've always used public static methods on "helper" classes that do not need `Util.caculate(..)`, and in the above "Car" example I wouldn't have use any private static or public static methods... just private and public methods.

Comment: Looks like the legacy java code is terrible...

Comment: I'm not sure your example really makes sense in terms of a Car. You would be starting or checking the gas of an instance of a Car, not all Car objects.

Comment: lol classic "put on hold" in 5 minutes ....i swear this site is really going down hill...thanks those who commented/answered   https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.vrbai5l1v

Comment: I think the unending string of "gimme teh codez" and "debug my program for me"  questions make people a little trigger happy on the close voting.

Comment: That's basically just procedual programming in an object oriented language. Design patterns are only applicable for object oriented programming. So the answer is probably "no".

Comment: that is a good point @Frank ,i can see that now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to limit access as tightly as possible, so if you have a utility class with some public static methods and some static helper methods that they call, those helper methods should be private.

This is not fundamentally different than writing non-static private helper methods to support non-static public methods.

I wouldn't call this a design pattern, so much as a good general practice.

Don't make things public unless you have to. Once a method is public, you can't modify its signature without breaking everything that uses it.

### Edit

Regarding the best place to put static methods, I'd rather put them on the class they're designed to help, rather than aggregate random static methods in a "Util" class.

A good example of this would be the [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class, which can be instantiated to represent a numerical value, but also has many static helper methods like `compare`, `max`, `parseInt`, etc.

Utility classes should be for things that are truly generic, such as the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.